# Java- I want to change a particular string with another one

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class OptimusPrime{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Please enter the sentence");
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

        String bucky=scan.nextLine();

        int pOs=bucky.indexOf("is");
        System.out.println(pOs);

        if(pOs==-1){
            System.out.println("the statement is invalid for the question");
        }
        else{
            String nay=bucky.replace("is", "was");
            System.out.println(nay);
        }
        }   
}
```

Now I know the "replace" method is wrong as i want to change the particular string "is" and not the portion of other string elements. I also tried using SetChar method but I guess the "string is immutable" concept applies here.
How to go about it?

Comment: Could you provide an example illustrating what's wrong with using `replace` in your code?

Comment: Please, format all the code because there are some lines not formatted. Also, please tell us the error that you've got.

Comment: Replace " is " rather than "is". i.e. Surround it with spaces.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It will replace not only the word "is" but so the occurrence of "is" in other words.

Comment: explain your question better please

Comment: the code your provided is working perfectly on my machine using eclipse IDE

Comment: do you men to replace only the first occurrence of "is" not the others? if so then you can use replaceFirst(regex, stringreplacement)

Comment: Example- "Android is my friend and I am Isthumus" If i use the aforementioned code then the o/p its showing " Android WAS my friend and I am WASthumus". I want to replace "is" as a separate string not embedded in word ISTHUMUS

Answer (score 2):

Using `String.replaceAll()` instead enables you to use a regex. You can use the predefined [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) \W in order to catch a non-word character :

```
System.out.println("This is not difficult".replaceAll("\\Wis", ""));
```

Output :

```
This not difficult
```

The verb `is` disappeared but not the `is`from `This`.

**Note 1** : It also removes the non-word character. If you want to keep it, you can capture it with some parenthesis in the regex then reintroduce it with `$1`:

```
System.out.println("This [is not difficult".replaceAll("(\\W)is", "$1"));
```

Output :

```
This [ not difficult
```

**Note 2** : If you want to handle a string which begins with `is`, this line will not be enough but it is quite easy to handle with another regex.

```
System.out.println("is not difficult".replaceAll("^is", ""));
```

Output :

```
 not difficult
```

Comment: Thanks! will try to implement this and will revert back!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `replaceAll` instead, then you can use `\b` to use the *word boundary* to perform a ["whole words only" search](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

See this example:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println(replace("this is great", "is", "was"));
    System.out.println(replace("crysis", "is", "was"));
    System.out.println(replace("island", "is", "was"));
    System.out.println(replace("is it great?", "is", "was"));
}

private static String replace(final String source, final String replace, final String with) {
    return source.replaceAll("\\b" + replace + "\\b", with);
}
```

The output is:

> this was great
>   crysis
>   island
>   was it great?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way:

```
String nay = bucky.replaceAll(" is ", " was ");
```

**Match word boundary**:

```
String nay = bucky.replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "was");
```

Comment: yes that's correct but it will replace every "is" in the sentence as well as other words  having those two alphabets.

Comment: @jadeblue Please share example. Match word boundary is perfect.

Comment: @JadeBlue You can check the examples in my answer to see, that this is not a problem with a "boundary check".

Comment: public static void main(String[] args){
 
  String bucky="rajesh is a good developer and this is tough job";
  
  int pOs=bucky.indexOf("is");
  System.out.println(pOs);
  
  if(pOs==-1){
   System.out.println("the statement is invalid for the question");
  }
  else{
   String nay=bucky.replace("is", "was");
   System.out.println(nay);
  }
  
  
  
 }

Comment: @jRajesh- Output is "rajesh was a good developer and thwas was tough job"

Answer (score -2):

to replace string with another string you can use this
if Your string variable contains like this

```
bucky ="Android is my friend";
```

Then you can do like this

```
bucky =bucky.replace("is","are");
```

and your bucky's data will be like this Android are my friend
Hope this helps you.

Comment: oh I didnt read the next questions of yours . my bad you can use like this also bucky = bucky.repaceall(" is ","was");  just give space to both side of is